# When typing a long string in Sublime Text, how does one indent the string so it is easier to read?

Tags: string, sublimetext2, paragraph

I want to type a paragraph and I don't want to scroll left and right to read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Preferences -> Settings - User`, set the following:

```json
"word_wrap": true,
"wrap_width": 0
```

This turns on word wrap for however wide your window is. If you want to wrap at a certain place, such as column 80, set `"wrap_width"` to that number.

All general Sublime settings (those not related to plugins) can be found by browsing through `Preferences -> Settings - Default`. Make sure you make any changes in `Preferences -> Settings - User`, though.